# adding single space between characters and multiple spaces between words

Tags: python

I have a string to morse function, right know I have it where there is a single space between the morse characters and if there were multiple words still would have a single space. How do I do 4 spaces between each word and keep the single space between the characters? I have added encodeChartoMorse function

```
def encodeChartoMorse(text_input):
  char=text_input.upper()
  if (char == "A"):
    char= ".-"
  elif (char == "B"):
    char= "-..."
  elif (char== "C"):
    char= "-.-."
  elif (char == "D"):
    char= "-.."
  elif (char == "E"):
    char= "."
  elif (char == "F"):
    char= "..-."
  elif (char == "G"):
    char= "--."
  elif (char == "H"):
    char= "...."
  elif (char == "I"):
    char= ".."
  elif (char == "J"):
    char= ".---"
  elif (char == "K"):
    char= "-.-"
  elif (char == "L"):
    char= ".-.."
  elif (char == "M"):
    char= "--"
  elif (char == "N"):
    char= "-."
  elif (char == "O"):
    char= "---"
  elif (char == "P"):
    char= ".--."
  elif (char == "Q"):
    char= " --.-" 
  elif (char == "R"):
    char= ".-."
  elif (char == "S"):
    char= "..."
  elif (char == "T"):
    char= "-" 
  elif (char == "U"):
    char= "..-" 
  elif (char == "V"):
    char= "...-"
  elif (char == "W"):
    char= ".--"
  elif (char == "X"):
    char= "-..-"
  elif (char == "Y"):
    char= "-.--"
  elif (char == "Z"):
    char= "--.."
  else:
    char= '*'
  
  return char



 def encodeStringtoMorse(text_input):
  
  length=len(text_input)
  morse=''
  for x in range(0, length):
    char= encodeChartoMorse(text_input[x])
    morse=morse + ' ' + char

  return morse
```

Comment: How are words separated in your `text_input` string?

Comment: can You show the encodeChartoMorse function?

Comment: I have added the function above

Comment: Well, maybe you've noticed that there's a certain character that always appears between words? Maybe you can think of something you could "translate" that to for the morse code output, in order to create the desired spacing?

Answer (score 2):

Unlike many other programming languages, Python lets you loop over elements in a list of letters in a word without having to use indices.  In this case, you need to loop over the words in the text (putting 4 spaces between encoded-words) and for each word, loop over each letter (putting 1 space between encoded letters). Lastly, Python dictionaries are efficient ways to map keys (such as letters) to values (such as morse codes) without resorting to if-then-else logic.

Edit: Per the comment below, when I said above to "loop over the words in the text" it is a fair question to ask how is that accomplished?  In my example, I broke the text string into separate words using Python's `split()` string method. It tries to create a list of sub-strings from a string by looking for spaces (by default) to split the string by. The resulting list gives us a handy way to loop over the words in the text as part of the encoding process.

Example:

```py
letter_to_morse = {
    "A": ".-",
    "B": "-...",
    "C": "-.-.",
    "D": "-..",
    "E": ".",
    "F": "..-.",
    "G": "--.",
    "H": "....",
    "I": "..",
    "J": ".---",
    "K": "-.-",
    "L": ".-..",
    "M": "--",
    "N": "-.",
    "O": "---",
    "P": ".--.",
    "Q": " --.-",
    "R": ".-.",
    "S": "...",
    "T": "-",
    "U": "..-",
    "V": "...-",
    "W": ".--",
    "X": "-..-",
    "Y": "-.--",
    "Z": "--..",
}

def encode_text_to_morse(text):
    text_list = text.upper().split()
    for word in text_list:
        morse_word = []
        for letter in word:
            morse_word.append(letter_to_morse.get(letter, "*"))
        char_space = " "
        word_space = "    "
        print(char_space.join(morse_word), end=word_space)


encode_text_to_morse("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog")
```

Output:

```
- .... .      --.- ..- .. -.-. -.-     -... .-. --- .-- -.     ..-. --- -..-     .--- ..- -- .--. ...     --- ...- . .-.     - .... .     .-.. .- --.. -.--     -.. --- --.
```

Comment: This is useful technique, but you should focus on the part where you solved the reported problem and explaining how that works (using `.split()`). This isn't codereview.SE.

Comment: I have not learned dictionaries so, I cannot understand this. Do I need the nested for loop?

Comment: Using a dictionary is a nice-to-have, not a must-have, since it simplifies the code, but your original char-to-morse function is a perfectly usable alternative.  Nested for loops are important since you are looping over each word in the message and for each word you need to loop over each letter to encode it.